# Finding the nearest neighbor Algorithm using google map coordinates

Tags: php, algorithm, coordinates

Please help me to find an algorithm that finds the nearest neighbor by its coordinates (latitude/longitude) I will implemented it using PHP

for example.  we have 1 client and 2 nodes
Node 1 = 32.9697, -96.8032 and Node 2=42.9697, -97.80322

each node has their own given coordinates (place on a map).

the client will send a latitude and longitude coordinates into the system and the system will find out if the coordinates that it receives from the client is near to Node 1 or Node 2

Please excuse my grammar. Hoping for your kind response. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only a limited number of possible targets (as I would guess from your question) you can use the following function ([copied from here](http://snipplr.com/view/2531/calculate-the-distance-between-two-coordinates-latitude-longitude/)) and just iterate over all your targets to find the closest one.

```
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = false)
{
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $pi80;
    $lng1 *= $pi80;
    $lat2 *= $pi80;
    $lng2 *= $pi80;

    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c;

    return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

If you have  many possible locations (>=10^4) you should organise those data points in some structure to only have to evaluate a fraction of them. I'd suggest a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for this although it will not work for the poles as well as the datum-border. I'm sure you'll find better solutions if needed for such a case (which I assume you do not require).

Comment: Thank you for the answer this function would be helpful to my implementation. anyway can you explain me about the target? how do I implement it which part of the code?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Simply run through all your nodes, calculate the distance to your client using the function and the node with the smallest distance is your nearest neigbour

Comment: I mean where do I place my specific target for e.g node1 and node2 their given coordinates for evaluation of nearest neighbor